# Get array updated from factory (Angular js)

Tags: angularjs, arrays, controller, factory

I have an array declared in the factory with the name **"voci"**, 
then i have a controller that update the array with a function **"CalcolaTotaleEuroPagine"**, what i want is to access to the array **"voci"** updated and print in the view, but it don't work.
Herewhat i have done:

**JS**

```
var LandingApp = angular.module('LandingApp',[]);

//SERVICE THAT RETURN ARRAY
LandingApp.factory('PreventivoTotaleFront', function () {
   var voci = {};
   voci.lista = [];

   return {
      add: function (voce) {
         voci.lista.push({
            id: voci.lista.length,
            costo: voce
         });
        console.log(voci);
     }
   };
   return voci;
});


//CONTROLLER THAT UPDATE ARRAY
LandingApp.controller('numberpages',function($scope,PreventivoTotaleFront){

   $scope.primapagina = 150;
   $scope.altrepagine = 90;
   $scope.numeroaltrepagine = 0;
   $scope.TotaleEuroPagine = 0;

   $scope.CalcolaTotaleEuroPagine = function(){
       return $scope.TotaleEuroPagine = $scope.altrepagine * $scope.numeroaltrepagine + $scope.primapagina;
       PreventivoTotaleFront.add(TotaleEuroPagine);
   };

});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="LandingApp">
    <div class="container">

        <form ng-controller="numberpages">

            <label>N° Pagine interne: </label><input type="number" min="0" ng-model="numeroaltrepagine" ng-change="CalcolaTotaleEuroPagine()"></input>
            <br/>{{TotaleEuroPagine | currency:""}}€<br/>

             <!--PRINT THE ARRAY VOCI-->
            <div>{{voci}}</div>
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is misorder of statement

```
$scope.CalcolaTotaleEuroPagine = function(){
return $scope.TotaleEuroPagine = $scope.altrepagine * $scope.numeroaltrepagine + $scope.primapagina;
PreventivoTotaleFront.add(TotaleEuroPagine);
};
```

you returned from the function before calling the factory. Hence the factory does not update the array. 
Put `PreventivoTotaleFront.add(TotaleEuroPagine);` this line before return statement

Comment: Now it return TypeError: dbg is undefined in the console.log

Comment: $scope.TotaleEuroPagine = $scope.altrepagine * $scope.numeroaltrepagine + $scope.primapagina;
PreventivoTotaleFront.add(TotaleEuroPagine);
return $scope.TotaleEuroPagine;

Comment: Now it works, but it don't print the array {{voci}} out in the view

Comment: i think you are directly trying to access the service variable. Access it through controller. As $scope.vociArr = PreventivoTotaleFront(); add this line in your controller. And in the view {{vociArr}}

Comment: hmm, thank you but i was trying a way to update factory data to share between more controllers

Comment: I think if you console log the data in the factory, you would get the updated data there. Because we are calling the add function. All i can say is, this is the correct way, but there may be some issue with implementation. Please  try to debug step by step. This is right track